# PHPWord Create A multiple table

Tags: cakephp, phpword

I am working with PHPWord... i create a table on the upper part of the document then i create my second table on the middle part of the document. Now whats happened is that the two table merge... is there a closing tag like a close tag in html for the table? or what should be the best way to create a new table using PHPWord?
TIA :D

Answer (score 4):

Just add an empty paragraph between the two tables

$section->addText("");

```
include('includes/PHPWord.php');
include('includes/PHPWord/Writer/Word2007.php');


$word = new PHPWord();

$styleTable = array('borderColor'=>'006699',
              'borderSize'=>6,
              'cellMargin'=>50);
$styleFirstRow = array('bgColor'=>'66BBFF');
$word->addTableStyle('myTable', $styleTable, $styleFirstRow);

$word->setDefaultFontName('Tahoma');
$word->setDefaultFontSize(10);

$section = $word->createSection();

$table = $section->addTable();

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 3");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 4");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 5");

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 3");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 4");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 5");

$section->addText("");

$table = $section->addTable();

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 3");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 4");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 5");

$table->addRow(200);
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 1");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 2");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 3");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 4");
$table->addCell(1200)->addText("Col 5");

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($word,'Word2007');
$objWriter->save("test.docx");
```